# Accessing static variables in a test package

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, junit, static-variables

I am working on a project in NetBeans and my project is made using JavaFX,Java and mysql. I have a controller class for every display page(fxml file) that has some static variables. When I try to access those static variables anywhere within the source package I successfully get their current values but when I try doing so from the test package it returns a null value or zero value. I am writing some junit tests and I need those current values of the static variables as the tests test those values.What should I do? Any suggestion would be helpful.
To be specific I have two display pages that calculate salary of an employee -one takes input from the user such as basic salary, other allowances and it's controller class stores those values in static variables accessed in the second page controller class to calculate net salary. The variable basicsalary shows zero value in the junit test class at the same time shows the correct value when accessed in salary2 class(the display page controller). I wish to access it's current value in the test class as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you, we really need to see the code and declarations that you have made. A verbal description of what you think your code does does not help.

Comment: Try to create a [mcve] and include it in the question. Are you using relative paths anywhere? Are GUI controls involved and if so are you using TestFX? BTW: It would be preferable to avoid the use of `static`. This makes controling the lifecycle of the object much simpler which also simplifies testing. The use of `static` usually indicates that you haven't properly set up a way of passing data to where it's needed. E.g. dependency injection frameworks could deal with this for you...

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the static values in your tests also. This will make your code more safe (for example if someone modified a static constant without wanting that, the test will fail).

That being said, you should have access to static variables in test classes as long as code compiles. Are the values assigned in another context? (like system variables, server startup...)

Comment: The values are entered at runtime, they are not static but the variables are and they don't have a different context.

Comment: can you debug while running the test to see if the static variable is assigned correctly?

Comment: I am sorry I should edit my question a little bit more.